# Python Multiprocess issues process not starting

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote this code, I want to have a main thread that starts multiple subprocesses that spawn a listener thread to wait for a kill message subprocess works but testprocess does not run there are no errors any ideas?

```
   from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
   from threading import Thread
   import time

   Alive = True 

   def listener_thread(conn): #listens for kill from main 
        global Alive
        while True:
        data = conn.recv()
        if data == "kill":
           Alive = False #value for kill 
           break

    def subprocess(conn):
        t = Thread(target=listener_thread, args=(conn,))
        count = 0 
        t.start()
        while Alive:
              print "Run number = %d" % count
              count = count + 1 


    def testprocess(conn):
    t = Thread(target=listner_thread, args=(conn,))
    count = 0 
    t.start()
    while Alive:
          print "This is a different thread run = %d" % count
          count = count + 1

    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=subprocess, args=(child_conn,))
    p2 = Process(target=testprocess, args=(child_conn,))
    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
    p.start()
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(runNum) 
    parent_conn.send("kill") #sends kill to listener thread to tell them when to stop
    p.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo in `testprocess` makes the function to quit early.

`listner_thread` should be `listener_thread`.

If you comment out `subprocess` related code and run the code, you will see following error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "t.py", line 25, in testprocess
    t = Thread(target=listner_thread, args=(conn,))
NameError: global name 'listner_thread' is not defined
```

Comment: Oh wow it was right in front of me. Now they both run but process goes infinite back to debugging thanks!

Comment: @KyleSponable, BTW, you need to call `parent_conn.send("kill")` twice.

Comment: so I would need to call that as many times as I have open threads?

Comment: @KyleSponable, Yes. `alive` in one process does not affect `alive` in another process.